# rqt_robot_dashboard Icon Size

Tags: rqt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If I wanted to take an existing rqt_robot_dashboard widget, say, [the PR2 motors widget](https://github.com/PR2/rqt_pr2_dashboard/blob/hydro-devel/src/rqt_pr2_dashboard/pr2_motors.py), and make the button twice as large, how would I do that?

(Don't suggest changing the size on [line 63](https://github.com/PR2/rqt_pr2_dashboard/blob/hydro-devel/src/rqt_pr2_dashboard/pr2_motors.py#L63) because that just makes the area surrounding the icon larger, not the actual icon)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/216436/rqt_robot_dashboard-icon-size/) by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10932 on 2015-08-24

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had some fun recently with this.  My solution/understanding turned out to be three parts:

- Icons (svg format in my case) need to have their internal size at least as large as you are trying to do with the icon. (bizarre to me).
- In rqt_robot_dashboard, where self.max_icon_size is set in setup(); I think this dictates a "canvas" size per button on the dashboard.
- In e.g. nav_view_dash_widget.py, self.setFixedSize can scale the icons.  I ended up doing (and then getting distracted by other things):

  ```
    # Old version:
    #self.setFixedSize(self._icons[0].actualSize(QSize(50, 30)))
    # New version, larger, more absolute:
    self.setFixedSize(QSize(100,60))
  ```

Caveat: I'm working with a derived version of rqt_dash for Fetch robots, so I've been playing with ever so slightly different code.  Nor have I fully wrested control of the rqt_dashboard setup to my liking.

---

Originally posted by [erelson](https://answers.ros.org/users/25756/erelson/) with karma: 26 on 2016-01-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2016-02-01**:
Thanks. I'll try this out soon.

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2016-02-24**:
"Soon"

A combination of three things fixed it for me.

- Resizing the svg (your point 1)
- Setting max_icon_size in my setup (your point 2)
- Not calling setFixedSize in the widget.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This line in the dashboard code proper might be causing problems:
https://github.com/ros-visualization/rqt_robot_plugins/blob/master/rqt_robot_dashboard/src/rqt_robot_dashboard/dashboard.py#L54

If you change it there too maybe that will help. Sorry for the sloppy coding on my part.

Below is the email exchange we already had for posterity in the hopes it might help some wayward soul:

> Aaron: You already modded the actual size of the svg right? I think they can only get smaller?
>
> David Lu!!: Nope. I'm not an svg expert.
>
> Aaron: Me neither but I think the icon can only shrink in Qicon.
> No promises but if you figure out how to make it bigger and then bump the number you mentioned before it will probably be bigger.
>
> David Lu!!: No dice. My 300x300 png still shows up tiny.

---

Originally posted by [Aaron Blasdel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3372/aaron-blasdel/) with karma: 211 on 2015-08-26

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2015-09-01**:
Sadly, this doesn't work. I tried setting max_icon_size before the constructor, but it did not affect anything.

**Comment by [Adolfo Rodriguez T](https://answers.ros.org/users/410/adolfo-rodriguez-t/) on 2015-09-02**:
`QIcon`s resize fine when used in widgets like push buttons or inside list/table/tree cells. `QToolButton`s might be different. The [docs](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qtoolbutton.html) mention two ways to set icon size. Have you tried setting it from the `QToolButton` itself?.

**Comment by [Aaron Blasdel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3372/aaron-blasdel/) on 2015-09-03**:
Shoot. I recall wrestling with sizing when I originally created it... I won't have any time to check this out again till late next week. Sorry DLu!!

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2015-09-07**:
@Adolfo: Setting the size hints did not work for me.

**Comment by [Aaron Blasdel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3372/aaron-blasdel/) on 2015-09-15**:
I'm going to create a dashboard for the fetch when I get a chance. When I do I'll look into this again.

**Comment by [Aaron Blasdel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3372/aaron-blasdel/) on 2016-01-27**:
One of our talented engineers over here at fetch figured this out (note: not me).

Seems it was a combo of what we were trying and a max size set in the svg. He knows more and will post soonish.